# Publish web package adding tasks to copy files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

I have an ASP.NET web package deployment using Visual Studios 2012 in which I would like to copy off files before deployment and then copy them back once deployment is completed.  These files happen to be under `Content\upload`.  If I just `deploy.cmd` the files are deleted and so currently I need to copy them off manually and then copy them back once deployment is complete.  I have tried several examples of similar situations for adding tasks to the Project file as well as extra files added to the project, such as:

- Adding tasks inside targets I have created called `Name="BeforePublish"` `Name="AfterPublish"` in the Project file.

  ```
  <Target Name="BeforePublish">
       <Message Text="BeforePublish"/>
       <Copy/>
  </Target>
  ```
- Adding file called `ProjectName.wpp.targets` and adding

  ```
  <Project>
      <Target Name="CopyMyFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
           <Message Text="CopyMyFiles called"/>
           <Copy/>
      </Target>
  </Project>
  ```

Neither of these techniques seem to be called.  Any other ideas?  Where and how should I put these tasks?

Comment: I would put your question in ServerStack instead...

Comment: Are you publishing directly from VS, or are you creating a deployment package (.zip), then later deploying the .zip file?

Comment: I am creating a deployment package then logging onto the server and running the deploy.cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually solve this using a skip rule. Try calling your command file like this:

```
deploy.cmd -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=Content\\uploads$
```

For more information on the skip directive, see [Web Deploy Operation Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Excellent.  I will use that.  One question though.  When deploying with my team we like to keep deployment strategy consistent.  Is there a way to wrap that somehow so that something can be called, such as even a .bat file.  We may be moving to one click deployment.  Could there be a strategy that can be used for that?